# sending full address of google to external page

Tags: javascript

i use this code for getting referral address .

```
<script>ducument.wrtie(document.referrer);</script>
```

and work correct for google and back full url like this :

```
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AD%DB%8C%20%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%84%D9%87%20%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%AA%DB%8C%20%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%B2&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEYQFjAD&url=www.mysite.com/1392/02/%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%AA-%DA%A9%D9%88%DA%86%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D9%87%D9%88%D8%B4%D9%85%D9%86%D8%AF-%D8%AF%D9%86%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D9%86%D8%A7/&ei=NT2KUZLhHsb40gHInoCYDQ&usg=AFQjCNG9PKNl1UBdaLNudIpnmdqCWhQX_A
```

but when send to external php page by below code

```
<script src="mysite.com/ntg.php?token=12948&referrer="+document.referrer></script>
```

only send this address for all keyword search

```
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` has a special meaning in URLs.

If you want to include it as data, you have to encode it.

Use [the `encodeURIComponent` JavaScript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).